# Unable to get posted FormData form data in php

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am using Angular in this code to send formData  to my upload.php file and then from upload.php, copying file to another Direcrtory and insert its address to MySQL musiclist data base  but my code isn't working and not even showing any Error I don't know what to do
Any help would be Appreciable

```
 <body>
 <div class="container" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="cntrl">
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="file" file-input="files">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="uploadfile()">upload</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="cntrl">
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="file" file-input="files">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="uploadfile()">upload</button>
 </div>
 </div>
  </body>
   </html>
  <script>
  var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
 app.directive("fileinput", function($parse){
        return{
            link : function($parse,element,attrs){
                element.on("change", function(event){
                     var files = event.target.files;
                     $parse(attrs.fileInput).assign(element[0].files);
                     $scope.apply();

                });

            }

        }

});
app.controller("cntrl",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.uploadfile = function(){
        var form_data= new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files, function(file){

            form_data.append('file',file);


        });
        $http.post('upload.php', form_data,
        {

            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers{'Content-Type': undefined ,'Process-Data': false}
        }).success(function(response){
            alert(response);
        });

    }

});
```

upload.php Code is

```
<?PHP

  $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","musiccloud");
 if(!empty($_FILES)){

$path='uploads/'.$_FILES['file'['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path))
{
    $Insertquery= "INSERT INTO musiclist(name) VALUES('".$_FILES['file'] 
 ['name']."')";
    if(mysqli_query($connect,$Insertquery))
    {

            echo 'file Uploaded';

    }
    else{

        echo 'file Not Uploaded';
    }


}

}

else{

echo 'some Error';
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: There's a multitude of syntax errors in this code that will prevent it from working until they're fixed. Check your error logs for details. If they're empty, you need to configure your error logging properly.